# What's the difference between $var[] = array() and $var = array()?

Tags: php, arrays

When I wrote `$var = array('index' => 'some value')`, it showed me an error when displaying a form on a page on the browser:

`Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\php\admin\authors\form.html.php on line 28.`

But when I wrote it like this `$var[] = array('index' => 'some value')`, it showed the page perfectly. So I have to put [] after variable name. In my knowledge, I can create an array variable like this `$var = array(some array)`.

So actually what is the difference between those two?

Comment: $var = array('index' => 'some value') is a valid PHP statement. There is no error in it. Can you still find when you get that undefined offset error. It should have come, when you try to use array with key value "0". Please check the same

Comment: According to your question, the difference is $var[] assigns value to existing key,say 0.$var directly gets the array and it simply is assigning array to a variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The results are different:

```
$var = array('index' => 'some value');
var_dump($var);

// array(1) {
//   ["index"]=>
//   string(10) "some value"
// }

$var[] = array('index' => 'some value');
var_dump($var);

// array(1) {
//   [0]=>
//   array(1) {
//     ["index"]=>
//     string(10) "some value"
//   }
// }
```

If you look closely, the first example creates an associative array with one key pair. The second example creates an array that contains one item at index 0; that one item being the associative array.

Answer (score 3):

When you wrote $var = array('index' => 'some value'), you can't access $var[0], cause this index doesn't exist. You have to use $var['index'] to access the value.

Using $var[] = array(..), you push array() into $var, so it's create a new entry with index 0. If you use var_dump($var), you will have :

```
array([0] => array(['index'] => 'somevalue'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do.. `$var[]=array();`

An empty array is stored as the first index inside the `$var` array..

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

If you do.. `$var = array();`

You are just declaring it `$var` as an array.

```
Array
(
)
```

#### So obviously, you know what the difference is...

<kbd>[A simple demo](https://eval.in/138507)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

`$var[] = array()` is a two dimensional array its like saying.

```
 $var = array(); // 1 dimensional array
 $var[0] = array();
```

try using `var_export($var)` in your two different examples to see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

`$var = array('index' => 'some value')` means a variable with an array value inside

`$var[] = array('index' => 'some value')` means an array with another array in the last index.
This is the same of write `$var = array(array('index' => 'some value'))`